# Swift check if two object have the same values

Tags: swift, firebase

I have an app that is location-based and I have two types of posts, `Fixed` & `Dynamic` I'm trying to set it up so that if a `Dynamic Post` and a `Fix Post` are at the same location it won't show the `Dynamic Post` and only show the `Fixed Post`. I just can't seem to figure out the logic behind it... Thanks for any help

**Heres as far as I was able to get:**

```
let ref = Database.database().reference().child("posts")
    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in

        guard let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else { return }
        dictionary.forEach { (key, value) in

            guard let dict = value as? [String: Any] else { return }

            guard let type = dict["type"] as? String else { return }
            guard let latitudeString = dictionary["latitude"] as? String else { return }
            guard let longitudeString = dictionary["longitude"] as? String else { return }

            let latitude = (latitudeString as NSString).doubleValue
            let longitude = (longitudeString as NSString).doubleValue

            var dynamicEvents = [Post]()

            Database.fetchPost(postId: key) { (post) in

                if post.type == "dynamic" && post.latitude == post.latitude && post.longitude == post.longitude {

                    let coords = [CLLocation(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)]
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.addAnnotation(post: post, title: post.category, subtitle: nil, coords: coords)
                    }
                } else {
                    return
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're not even attempting to compare two post, all your code does is needlessly check if post's lat/lon are equal to themselves.

Comment: @Gereon that’s why I made the question. I was unsure on why it wasn’t working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to create an extension to compare between those object. 
Or you can make these 2 objects inherit from an object which contains both : "latitude" & "longitude". In this way, you can implement the Equatable protocol to compare if they are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is checking if the same variable is equal to the same variable:

post.latitude == post.latitude && post.longitude == post.longitude

I think you meant something like

post.latitude == latitude && post.longitude == longitude